# Which port does Eclipse use while installing/updating plugins?

Tags: installation, download, eclipse

I am trying to Install a plugin in Eclipse 3.6. However, I keep getting `http server not implemented errors` while trying to install it.

[image]

If I install the same plugin using a 3G data card, the error doesn't come. I have been told that the error is because our office Firewall blocks the ports required by Eclipse.

I have to report this error and the ports that are blocked to the System admin so that they can unblock the ports. Can any one please tell me which port numbers are used, or how I can find out which ports are used by Eclipse so that I can ask them to open the ports?

Answer (score 0):

When I perform an update check, only ports `80` and `443` (for HTTPS most likely) are used.

Maybe it's a proxy that's causing you trouble?